# Alternate ways of getting value of Variables that were optimized out of stack when Core was collected, after a crash

Tags: c++, c, gdb, coredump

Sometimes, there is a system crash which happens due to some corner case scenario, which is highly difficult to reproduce. In such cases, to debug, Core file analysis is the only hope.
Using gdb on a core file, I am unable to check out the value of some variables, as the gdb says that the value has been optimized out.

```
(gdb) p index
$37 = <optimized out>
(gdb) info locals
index = <optimized out>
data_result = <optimized out>
level = 18
```

I understand that this happens due to the fact that stack must have switched the value of these local variables with other variables.

I know a couple of ways of rebuilding code and getting the desired values which were earlier optimized out :

1. Store the value of local variables in a global variable, as global variables are not optimized out in core collection.
2. Use keywords like static/ volatile - so that no optimization is done on the local variables which are of interest.

But, in both these cases, the problem is that - Some issues are not reproduced consistently - so, modifying code to get the optimized variable's value in GDB doesn't work.

There is another way that works sometime - depending on the code flow.

1. In case the local variable is being initialized by some global variable - then at that instance, instead of printing the value of the local variable, which has been optimized out - printing the value of the global variable gives us the result desired. --- This way is not full proof - and depends on code flow. Sometimes, local variable is initialized this way - sometimes, it isn't.

Any suggestions that would enable me to get the variable value would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can see the assembly and registers - ebp, esp and others and infer the variables.

Comment: I don't think there is any fool proof way. The compiler has optimised the value out for a reason - usually because it is no longer needed. So it is possible that you just can't get it directly at all. You'll need to go through the (often painstaking) task of trying to reconstruct or infer that value from other values in the core. This often requires looking at the assembly level instructions and register values. And there is no guarantee that there is enough info in the core for even that. Good luck!